# What is the most user friendly dateformat?

Tags: date, user-interface, usability, date-format

What is - from a usability point of view - the best way to format dates?

Should I rather use absolute dates like:

- 05.07.2011
- 07/05/2011

or would it be better to print dates relative to the current time:

- one week ago
- last Monday
- yesterday

Comment: Depends on the user and the locale.  There's no definitive answer for this.

Comment: Use month names (or their abbreviations) plus use four digit years (or prefix them with a `'`) so that dates are non ambiguous. From the first date you mentioned it is hard to determine whether it is *May 7* or *5 July*.

Comment: Well sure, using 05.07.2011 vs 07/05/2011 depends on the users locale. But using absolute vs relative ones does not

Comment: I like the phrases, but I think it'll only work for dates <= one week ago. You don't wont "1 month three weeks and 2 days ago"

Comment: If the question is "which is the most user friendly **absolute** date format", then +1 for depending on the locale. Otherwise, I know I appreciate when applications use "today", "yesterday" etc. when it's reasonable ("last Monday" would be pushing it, in my opinion). Or perhaps a combination. In any case, it depends on the context. Are the dates related to when a blog post was published? Or when a bank transaction took place? Etc.

Comment: It not only depends on the user and the locale but also the context of the GUI. Sometimes the must user friendly solution is "today" or "next thursday", or "aug 15" if a specific year is always assumed.

Comment: See http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/which-date-format-to-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all questions relating to the "best" way to do something there are no absolutes.

It will depend on how the dates are being used.

The only way to test what's best for your users is to ask them. That's one of the reasons for usability testing.

Comment: You don't even have to ask a lot of users, just a very few real users would tell you a lot more than asking strangers who don't know what your app does or what it is for.

Answer (score 3):

The relative dates are in my opinion the most user friendly for the following reasons:

- It doesn't depend on the users locale
- You dont have to think about how old the post is. In principle you have to calculate if its absolute

> I like the phrases, but I think it'll only work for dates <= one week ago. You don't wont "1 month three weeks and 2 days ago"

Well, you dont have to be that precise. But of cause it depends what the purpose is. If its just comments on a blog the 2 days would not matter.